# Create In-Ribbon Gallery in Action(Task)Pane

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, office365, customtaskpane

I'm trying to code a VSTO Word template (Office 365).

In Visual Studio I added an Actionpane Component. Now i want to add an In-Ribbon gallery on this pane. But it's not possible to add it on the visual designer (grayed out)

Has anyone an idea, how I can add some galleries?

I already tried a few DLLs from git. But doesn't work. The ribbon2Form didn't work too.